# Determine the value of p that will make the lines parallel and perpendicular.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The slopes of two lines are $\frac{5}{6}$ and $\frac{2}{p}$  .

Determine the value of $p$ that will make the lines

A) parallel

B) perpendicular

I understand how parallel lines have the same slope but different intercepts, and how lines that are perpendicular meet at right angles, but how do i go about finding the value of p for both?

Answer (score 3):

A) The lines will be parallel to each other if their slopes/gradients are equal, hence we get
$$\frac{5}{6}=\frac{2}{p}\iff p=\frac{12}{5}$$

B)  The lines will be perpendicular to each other if the product of their slopes/gradients is $-1$, hence we get 
$$\frac{5}{6}\times \frac{2}{p}=-1\iff p=\frac{-5}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Conditions A) and B) are mutually exclusive. Only one can be answered to reflect truth (value of $p$) at the same time.

A) slopes are same  $5/6=2/p\rightarrow p=2.4 $

B) slopes product is $-1; \,\dfrac{5}{6}\cdot \dfrac{2}{p}=-1,\,p\rightarrow  -5/3 $

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1013005)

Comment: Added calculation.